# codeigniter txt file upload

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I'm using codeigniter and I found a strange case when I try to upload some text files.

Using the method documentation indicating ([CI doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)) everything works fine, but if I try to upload the file contains the string ' // ' (without quotes) the result I get is "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Any idea?

Code used: (controller)

```
function do_upload() {
    $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH.'uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt|csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '1024';
    $config['max_width']  = '0';
    $config['max_height']  = '0';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    @var_dump($_FILES['userfile']);   // debug
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    } else 
        echo "<br>upload ok";
}
```

upload_form.php (view):

```
<?php 
    if (isset($error)) echo $error;
    echo form_open_multipart('supervisor/do_upload'); 
    echo form_label('File', 'userfile');
    echo form_upload('userfile');
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Upload');
    echo form_close() 
?>
```

For example: (.txt for upload)

```
[file1.txt]:
THIS IS A TEXT FILE     # work fine

[file2.txt]:
THIS IS A // TEXT FILE    # fail!  note: {blank}//{blank}
```

output (uploading file1.txt)

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "file1.txt" ["type"]=> string(10) "text/plain" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpLVaMGs" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(19) }
upload ok
```

output (uploading file2.txt)

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "file2.txt" ["type"]=> string(10) "text/plain" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpFu4znR" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(22) }

The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
...
```

Firebug POST: (uploading file2.txt)

```
userfile    THIS IS A // TEXT FILE
submit  Upload
Fuente
-----------------------------15028408581691128039842883428 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="file2.txt" 
Content-Type: text/plain 
THIS IS A // TEXT FILE 
-----------------------------15028408581691128039842883428 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit" 
Upload 
-----------------------------15028408581691128039842883428--
```

Comment: Try changing $config['allowed_types'] = 'txt|csv'; to $config['allowed_types'] = 'text|csv'; because that's the mime type

Comment: Why are you setting width and height? Try removing those configs and see if it still fails.

Comment: Thank you Pattle and cryptic for the suggestions.

@Pattle, had already tried that and other combinations but the result remains the same.

Comment: @cryptic ツ, you're right, this time _width_ and _height_ are not needed, but still fails even removing them.

I have also checked that fails with **//{blank}** at start of the line or **{blank}//** at end of the line

Comment: Right after you load the library run the following `var_dump($this->upload->do_upload());exit;` and tell me the output. Btw please post your form code and HTML as well.

Comment: @cryptic ツ, the output is `bool(false)`.. you can see the HTML form, it's a basic code i use for check

Comment: The strange thing is that everything works fine (as expected) while not put those characters in the contents of the text file.
I'm currently using ´$config['allowed_types'] = '*'´ to work properly, while I find the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Oskr does `abc//abc` fail or must it have a space *before* and *after* the `//` to fail? Btw what version of CI are you using?

Comment: @cryptic ツ I've only seen it fail with blanks .. using 2.1.2 CI version

Comment: Ok just like I made you do the var_dump above do it again but this time do this `var_dump($_FILES['userfile']);exit;` let's check to see if global is being populated. That is the first thing CI checks.

Comment: @cryptic ツ I edited the code to display more information. Is it possible that this is a bug of CI?. Because in short, everything works ok, then only add two characters `/` with some space within the text file and no longer works

Comment: I'm beginning to think that too. If it is you can head over here https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues and open up a bug report. But please look at the CI Upload.php file in `system/libraries` and do more debugging echo etc in the `do_upload()` before opening a bug.

Comment: Thanks @cryptic ツ , I looked a little above code but so far I have not seen very clear, I will try to better examine do_upload and specifically is_allowed_filetype function

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem several number of times and i always do the following fix while using a new system folder. And It's a CI bug. Please let me know is it works of not ???

**GO TO system/libraries/Uploads.php -- LINE NO 1059**

```
@exec('file --brief --mime-type ' . escapeshellarg($file['tmp_path']), $output, $return_code);
```

**CHANGED TO:**

```
@exec('file --brief --mime-type ' . escapeshellarg($file['tmp_name']), $output, $return_code);
```

**NOW look at line number 1044-1045** . It should looks like:

```
$this->file_type = @mime_content_type($file['tmp_name']);
return;
```

**CHANGE the return statement:**

```
$this->file_type = @mime_content_type($file['tmp_name']);
if(strlen($this->file_type) > 0) return;
```

Comment: Hello @mahbub.kuet, in the CI version i am using are applied the changes you propose. Specifically for the first line you say, is posed in this way: `$cmd = 'file --brief --mime ' . escapeshellarg($file['tmp_name']) . ' 2>&1';`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you wanna say. Would you please put your words in some other way or more elaborately ? 
However I applied those changes in `define('CI_VERSION', '2.1.0');`
What is your CI VERSION ??